# Fourth Normal Form

Tags: normalization

It's been about ten years since I paid real attention to fourth normal form, and my understanding of multi-value dependencies has seriously waned. How far is this table from 4NF and why?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Medicine](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BrandName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [GenericName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [PricePerUnit] [money] NOT NULL,
    [QuantityInStock] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AdminMethodId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PharmacistId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Medicine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You can't deduce normal forms without functional dependencies. What are the dependencies of the attributes of this relation?

Comment: None that I can see, between attributes, but I was thinking (probably wrong) that e.g. `PricePerUnit`, although only dependent on `Id`, is together with `BrandName` dependent on unit, and maybe separate tables should be used.